# devmem2 is not writing to the address specified

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am trying to change a variable's content of a program with devmem2. Simply:

```
static inline __attribute__ ((always_inline))
void clflush(volatile void *p)
{
    asm volatile ("clflush (%0)\n"::"r" (p):"memory");
}

uint64_t get_pfn(uint64_t entry) {
    return ((entry) & 0x3fffffffffffff);
}

uint64_t get_phys_addr(uint64_t v_addr) 
{
    uint64_t entry; 
    uint64_t offset = (v_addr/4096) * sizeof(entry);
    uint64_t pfn; 
    int fd = open("/proc/self/pagemap", O_RDONLY);
    assert(fd >= 0);
    int bytes_read = pread(fd, &entry, sizeof(entry), offset);
    close(fd);
    assert(bytes_read == 8);
    assert(entry & (1ULL << 63));
    pfn = get_pfn(entry);
    assert(pfn != 0);
    return (pfn*4096) | (v_addr & 4095);

}

int main(){
int a = 44;

uint64_t v_addr = (uint64_t) &a;
printf("%lx\n",v_addr);
uint64_t p_addr = get_phys_addr(v_addr);
printf("%lx\n",p_addr); 
clflush(&a);
sleep(20);

int b = a;
printf("value of b: %d\n",b);
printf("value of b: %d\n",a);
uint64_t v_addr2 = (uint64_t) &b;
printf("%lx\n",v_addr2);
uint64_t p_addr2 = get_phys_addr(v_addr2);
printf("%lx\n",p_addr2);    

}
```

I am trying to change the content of variable "a" while sleeping with devmem2. Consider that my program prints "17580fab8" as the physical address of "a". I am executing devmem2 in another tab like this:

`sudo devmem2 -x17580fab8 w 0x1235`
So, after sleeping 20 seconds, I would expect the value of a and b to 0x1235. However, they do not change. The output when I run devmem2 while my program sleeps is this:

```
/dev/mem opened.
Memory mapped at address 0x7f464d50c000.
Value at address 0x0 (0x7f464d50c000): 0x1235
Written 0x1235; readback 0x1235
```

devmem2 claims to "read/write from/to any location in memory". Is it wrong? Because how can it write to my program's pages?

Comment: I have no knowledge about how `/dev/mem` works, but wouldn't it be advisable to make `a` `volatile` if you aim to change it outside the program's control? Otherwise, the program can just assign `44` to `b` right off the bat.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `/dev/mem` cannot be used to modify the contents of RAM. It is only for accessing memory-mapped devices that don't have a kernel-mode driver.

Comment: If the kernel has been built with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y` configured, `/dev/mem` only provides access to PCI space and BIOS code and data regions. There are additional restrictions if `CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM=y` also - only idle regions not in use by device drivers can be accessed in that case.

Comment: I think you have a typo. `-x17580fab8` should be `0x17580fab8`. You are accessing physical address 0.